# Exception instantiating filter in Spring MVC web-app

Tags: java, exception, servlets, spring-mvc, filter

I need to enable *cross-origin resource sharing* in my RESTful service implemented using Spring MVC. The service works correctly, but now I need to access resources from another domain.

I found some posts suggesting to add a filter in my web-app. So I added this parts:

**Filter class**

```
package org.canvassservice.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null
                && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type, Accept");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

---

**In web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

**application.context**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.canvassservice.controllers" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="corsFilter" class="org.canvassservice.filters.CorsFilter" />

</beans>
```

But when I run my application, I get this exception (in Tomcat log):

```
GRAVE: Exception starting filter corsFilter java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

With no clear cause explained. Any idea about the problem?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried using `DelegatingFilterProxy` instead of `OncePerRequestFilter`, declaring the filter bean in `application.context`, but a new exception is thrown:

```
GRAVE: Exception starting filter corsFilter
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'corsFilter' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect a `CorsFilter` instance to be created if you specify

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

You're specifically telling the container to instantiate `OncePerRequestFilter`.

The solution you've proposed works

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.canvassservice.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

The container will instantiate and register a `CorsFilter` instance as a `Filter`. However, you won't be able to take advantage of Spring's lifecycle events and injection because the instance is not a Spring managed bean.

Instead, if you need all that setup magic, you can use a [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html). The `DelegatingFilterProxy` *delegates* to a `Filter` bean defined in your Spring `ApplicationContext`.

You can use the filter `<init-param>` with name `targetBeanName` to specify the id of the bean to delegate to. If you don't specify it, it will use the name defined in `<filter-name>`.

Comment: so should `CorsFilter` extend `DelegatingFilterProxy` instead of `OncePerRequestFilter`?

Comment: @davioooh No. Leave it as is. Just specify the bean's name. Instead of having a `<filter>` entry for `OncePerRequestFilter`, you would have one for `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

Comment: now I get a new exception `GRAVE: Exception starting filter corsFilter
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'corsFilter' is defined`. Note I declared filter bean in my `application.context`

Comment: @davioooh Can you post the rest of your `web.xml`? I think it might be looking in the wrong context.

Comment: You're right, I was declaring my bean in the wrong context! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved replacing the filter class with the concrete implementation:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.canvassservice.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

I also removed the bean declaration from `application.context` file.

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this problem, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This wont give the IOC availability in Filters, use

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```